# Check if days in month are weekends

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In this function I'm trying to check if days of a month are weekends or not. First I push all days in an array, then I push in another array every item =! 0 or 6, that are weekend days number. But if I read console log, my businessDays array contains all the days, not only business day.

```
getDaysArrayByMonth(year, month) {
        let numberOfDays = moment([year, month], "YYYY-MM LT").daysInMonth();
        const arrDays = [];
        const businessDays = [];
        while (numberOfDays) {
            const current = moment().date(numberOfDays);
            arrDays.push(current);
            numberOfDays--;
        }

        arrDays.forEach(item => {
            if (item.days() != 0 || item.days() != 6){
                businessDays.push(item)
            }
        });

        return businessDays;
    }

getDayArrayByMonth(2016, 11);
```

Comment: Like Mr. George has said below, your if statement is currently using OR instead of AND, so you're saying if the day isn't Sunday or if it isn't Saturday, push the day on, which means that all days will be added, you want to do AND to say if it's not a Sunday AND it's not a Saturday, add it to the array. || = or, && = and.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if statement is not correct

```
arrDays.forEach(item => {
   if (item.days() != 0 && item.days() != 6){
       businessDays.push(item)
   }
});
```